# Fetching the string from NSURL

Tags: iphone, string, nsurl

I have a `NSURL`

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

I want to get the "google" from this string , How can i do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can get just the domain part with this:

```
[url host]
```

...will get you `www.google.com`, then you'll need to do some regex/string replacement to strip off the `www.` and `.com` parts.

I'd suggest a regex something like the following:

```
\.?(.+)\.([a-z]{2,})$
```

...then pull out that first match for the part you want.